# Skolem functions in the real ordered field.

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

I am currently reading into a bit of model theory and have come across the idea of Skolem functions, as used in the proof of the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem. Despite seeing their use there I cannot get my head around how to create them, and I was hoping someone might be able to help?

If, for example, I was working in the real ordered field $\langle \mathbb{R};+,\cdot , -, 0 , 1,< \rangle$ how could I write down Skolem functions for;

1.) $x_1 < y$;

2.) $y < x_2$ and

3.) $x_1 < y < x_2$?

As you can see these are some of the easier things possible in this ordered field, and I am aiming to use these to get a grasp on creating the functions myself for other formulas.

Comment: Something is wrong there -- Skolem functions are not associated with arbitrary formulas, but _specifically_ with formulas that start with an existential quantifier. There's no $\exists$ in any of your formulas, so it's difficult to see how the concept of Skolem functions could apply to them at all.

Comment: (Are you implicitly considering the $y$s to be existentially quantified, perhaps?)

Comment: I would say the existential quantifier would be for the $x_1$ and $x_2$ instead of the $y$.

Answer (score 1):

"Skolem functions" mean slightly different things in different context, but in the usual proof of the downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem it goes something like this:

> Let $\mathcal L$ be a first-order language. Given an $\mathcal L$-structure $\mathfrak A$ and an existentially quantified $\mathcal L$-formula $\exists x.\varphi(x,y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, the function $f:\mathfrak A^n\to\mathfrak A$ is a **Skolem function** for $\varphi$ iff for all $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in\mathfrak A$, $$ \mathfrak A \vDash \varphi(f(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n),\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n) \lor \neg\exists x.\varphi(x,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n) $$

The proof then proceeds to choosing Skolem functions $f_\varphi$ for *every possible* well-formed $\exists x.\varphi$ in the language.

Usually when you give the proof you don't actually write down definitions for any of these Skolem functions -- you just appeal to the Axiom of Choice to conclude that appropriate Skolem functions *always exist* for every (non-empty) structure $\mathfrak A$ and formula $\varphi$. You don't get to *see* those Skolem functions concretely -- it is enough for the purpose of the proof that they *exist*.

If you have been asked, as an exercise, to construct some Skolem functions explicitly, it is **not** because the ability to construct Skolem functions is important, or because you should know any general procedure for doing so. The point of the exercise is simply to make sure you have understood what it *means* to be a Skolem function. Once you have this understanding, writing down an example is (in these easy cases) trivial.

For example, let's take $\mathfrak A=\mathbb R$ and the formula $\exists x.x^2=y$. Then for $f$ to be a Skolem function for $x^2=y$ it must be a function $\mathbb R^1\to\mathbb R$ (because $\exists x.x^2=y$ has one free variable, $y$), and it must satisfy
$$ \forall y.\quad f(y)^2=y \lor \neg\exists x.x^2=y $$

In other words, for every $y$ that *has* a square root, $f(y)$ must be a possible square root of $y$, but if $y$ has *no* square root then the value of $f$ is immaterial.

Once we understand what is required, it is simple to write down a lot of choices for $f$:

$$ \begin{align}
f_1(y) &= \sqrt{|y|} \\[1ex]
f_2(y) &= \begin{cases} \sqrt y & \text{if }y>0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \\[1ex]
f_3(y) &= \begin{cases} -\sqrt y & \text{if }y>0 \\ \pi & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \\[1ex]
f_4(y) &= \begin{cases} \sqrt{|y|} & \text{if }y\in \mathbb Q \\
                      -\sqrt{|y|} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \end{align} $$
and an infinity of other possibilities. All of these are equally good Skolem functions.

Comment: Okay this sounds slightly more like what I was thinking of; coming from the idea of a proof. But again how would this equate over to, for example;
$x_1 < y$?

Comment: @b0bg0blin: I think I have given you enough information to figure that out for yourself.

Comment: @b0bg0blin: You should also double-check that your text indeed wants the $x$s to be the existentially quantified. In particular, subproblem (3) of your exercise would make a lot more didactic sense if it's asking for a Skolem function for $\exists y.x_1<y<x_2$ than asking for one for $\exists x_1.\exists x_2.x_1<y<x_2$.

Comment: The text has no existential quantifiers in it at all; hence the edit back to how it originally was. In all fairness I (and others) have absolutely no idea what we are meant to be looking at. We have been given no definitions or ways of computing it. We saw one example, which was the square root over $\mathbb{C}$. For example it has taken three of us looking at the first subproblem to even attempt to attain;


$f(y)= y-1$ if $x_1 < y$ or $y$ otherwise - however this still feels incorrect. Apologies for the lack of array environment.

Comment: @b0bg0blin: You have _no definitions?_ You're probably screwed, then. For what it's worth, $f(y)=y-1$ looks right for $x_1<y$, _assuming_ that $x_1$ is supposed to be the variable whose place $f$ takes. But I still strongly suspect that it's the other way around, so the expected answer would be something like $f(x_1)=x_1+1$. Especially in the case of $x_1<y<x_2$ it would make much more sense to me to produce $y$ as a function of $x_1,x_2$ and answer $f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ than to answer $f(y,x_2)=y-1$, not least because $x_2$ would be completely irrelevant in the latter case.

Comment: @b0bg0blin: Um what I said looks correct is just $f(y)=y-1$. The "if $x_1<y$ or $y$ otherwise" is confused. The function is supposed to give you a possible $x_1$ as a function of $y$ (or the other way around, depending on how the definition you don't have goes), so it cannot depend on what $x_1$ is -- it's the job of the function to _produce_ an $x_1$.